# How to redirect form to a section of a different page?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

There is a contact us form on my Web Application. What I want is, when a user fills up the form and clicks on the submit button, it should redirect to a different page's section.

In this current case, contact99 section should be shown after loading the ContactUsServlet.jsp page. Following is my code:-

Contact Us form:-

```
<form action="ContactUs" method="post">
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required name="Name"></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required name="Email"></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required name="Subject"></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" required name="Message"></p>
      <p>
      </div>
        **<button class="w3-button w3-black" onclick="on()" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> SEND MESSAGE
        </button>**
      </p>
    </form>
    <!-- Image of location/map -->
    <img src="/w3images/map.jpg" class="w3-image w3-greyscale" style="width:100%;margin-top:48px">
  </div>
```

ContactUs Servlet:-

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name1=request.getParameter("name");
        String email1=request.getParameter("email");
        String subject1=request.getParameter("subject");
        String message1=request.getParameter("message");


        session.setAttribute("name01", name1);
        session.setAttribute("email01", email1);
        session.setAttribute("subject01", subject1);
        session.setAttribute("message01", name1);




   Test t=new Test(email1, "Support", "Hi "+name1+"\n \n"+"Thank you contacting us. We'll respond to your query as soon as possible"+"\n \n"+"Following is what you've written to us:- "+"\n \n"+message1);

   Test t1=new Test("emailid", "New query, query from new user "+name1+"", "Hi, A new user has sent a message."+"\n \n"+"User Email ID:- "+email1+"\n"+"User's subject:- "+subject1+"\n \n"+"User's message:- "+message1);


            try 
            {
                t.sendEmail();


              response.sendRedirect("ContactUsSuccess.jsp/#contact99");


                t1.sendEmail();
                System.out.println("Mail Sent successfully");
            } 

            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

            }
```

ContactUsSuccess.jsp:-

```
<!-- Contact Section -->
<div id="contact99">
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <strong>Success!</strong> Message sent successfully. Please check your mail for further details
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: And what is the problem? Looks right to me - perhaps not with the `/ ` - I would expect `ContactUsSuccess.jsp#contact99` or `/ContactUsSuccess#contact99`

Comment: Thank you. ContactUsSuccess.jsp#contact99 worked for me.

Comment: It was literally scrolling through the page to get to the #contact99 section. Do you know any technique by which it directly opens up in the #contact99 section?

Comment: Ajax could do that

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot